# Control the async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have two different Node.js programs.

One is an Express.js Server (`PROGRAM1`), which is to provide the user interface and RESTful APIs.

The other is a crawler (`PROGRAM2`), which keeps on reading item, download it from web and store everything into the database. By the way, I am using the `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Promise` to iterate the files and handle I/Os one by one orderly.

One thing I would like to do here, is to monitor and control the progress of the crawler(`PROGRAM2`) from the `PROGRAM1`.

But I found it very complicate.

```
// Control the loop by this `flag`, the value can be assigned from outside
var flag = "IDLE"; 
// The outside can read this `index`, and monitor the progress
var current_index = -1;
var PAGE_SIZE = 100;
function handleBatch(index){
   var defer = q.defer();
   // Mongoose statement to find documents...
   Book.find()
       .skip(index*PAGE_SIZE).limit(PAGE_SIZE).then(function(books){
           var finished = 0;
           for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++){
              var book = books[i];
              downloadInfo(book).then(function(bookInfo){
                  if(flag === "STOP")
                      defer.reject(new Error("The loop should stop!"));
                  //store the info...
                  finished ++;
                  if(finished === PAGE_SIZE)
                     defer.resolve();
              });
           }
       });
    return defer.promise;
}

var promiseHandler;
function main(){
   while(true){
       if(flag === "IDLE")
         continue;
       else if(flag === "START"){
          var [0,1,2,3,4,5...,2500].reduce(function(lastPromise, nextIndex){
             promiseHandler = lastPromise.then(function(){
                 currentIndex = nextIndex;
             });
          }, q());
       }else if(flag === "STOP"){
             promiseHandler.then(null, function(err){
                 flag = "IDLE";                     
             });
       }
   }      
}
```

`main()` is just an example(e.g. Actually it is a server, and the state can be changed by the requests from `PROGRAM1`). By setting the `flag` as `STOP`, the loop in `handleBatch()` will discover the change and throw an `Exception`, then the program will be paused.

However, I just don't like this way, because it looks too ugly and control the process by throwing Errors. So I am searching for a better way to control and monitor the loop. Any one any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the documentation for node.js' [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html).
And to answer your question about stopping the execution, here ->

> process.exit(0);

Just as a tip: don't control your program using a loop. It's bad.

Comment: Actually the `main()` is just the simulation of a server. I don't want to kill the process, and I just want it paused and be able to restart by signal...

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it you are after a way to implement inter-process communication in node js. This is a broad programming topic that goes way beyond node js. There's many patterns and means to achieve this, but one of my favourites is to use a message queue to loosely couple the two processes.

On node js we have things like [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) which can be used to implement a publish-subscribe pattern. Of course there's many messaging libraries that would work too.

In your case the Express API might publish a "pause" event, and the crawler could subscribe to that event and take some action. Your node apps then remain asynchronous (no while(true) nonsense!).

Comment: The problem is mainly focus on how to control the async loop, start/pause/restart the task, rather than the inter-process communication.

Comment: You describe the problem as having 2 programs that need to communicate - that's inter-process communication. If you are wanting to pass a control signal with a program wouldn't you just use a callback function? while(true) will use an entire CPU polling for a change in a variable - that's not how you program in javascript, that's how you write (poor) synchronous C.

Comment: I see, PROGRAM2 is just an example of server(as it is always runing and waiting for the request)...